# Index linq result using a dictionary or similar

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linqpad

I am using LINQ to SQL (through LINQPad) to extract some data from a MySQL database.

```
var res = MyTable.First();
res.Dump();
```

And I have 255 columns like so.

```
i0 | 0.01
i1 | 0.11
i2 | 4.01
...
i254 | 1.12
```

I would like to convert the values from the 255 columns into an array after the select. Is there a way to iterate through the value of `res` as a dictionary so it will be possible to make a loop like (in pseudo code):

```
for i in 0..254 do
    array[i] = res["i" + i]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @sloth I got it to work with reflection as so:

```
var type = res.GetType();
type.GetMembers().Where(s => s.Name.StartsWith("i")).Select(s => new { Name = s.Name, Value=s.GetValue(res)}).Dump();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection the get the properties.

**Example**:

```
var res = MyTable.First();
var type = res.GetType();
for(int i=0; i<=254; i++)
    array[i] = type.GetProperty("i" + i).GetValue(res);
```

Comment: @lejon Yeah; have to replace `1` with `i`